# Meteor Blaze To Do App checked condition

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

(Super new to meteor)

I've gone through the meteor todo app tutorial and on the [checking off and deleting tasks part](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/update-and-remove) It says that

> If you try checking off some tasks after adding all of the above code, you will see that checked off tasks have a line through them. This is enabled by the following snippet:

```
<li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}">
```

> With this code, if the checked property of a task is true, the checked
>   class is added to our list item. Using this class, we can make
>   checked-off tasks look different in our CSS.

Is there any way to have this apply to a different tag, and not the list? so basically have it say

> With this code, if the checked property of a task is true, the **updatedstyle**
>   class is added to our **img tag**. Using this class, we can make
>   checked-off tasks **make images** look different in our CSS.

Comment: It's just like an ```if else``` statement but works inside a ```template```. You can use it for any html elements. Eg, ```<img src={{#if bigImage}} "/soucre/to/big/image.jpg" {{else}} "/source/to/small/image.jpg" {{/if}} />``` At present, conditional statements in templates can only check truth values. Other operators are not supported out of the box. But what is it that you're actually wanting to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `{{#if}}` anywhere you want in your template, not just in the list item. If I understand your specific question:

```
<li>Some item
  <img class="{{#if checked}}updatedstyle{{/if}}" src="/myImg.png">
</li>
```

Per @blueren, the parameter to the `{{#if}}` is evaluated as a *truthy* or *falsy* value. It can be a key in the current data context (i.e. `this.checked`) or can be returned by a helper.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a class reactively binded to html tag in the template, you can do it like that:

Template code:

```
<template name="MyTemplate">
  <img src="my/img/path.jpg" class={{checked.img}}/>

  <ul>
    <li class={{checked.li}}>My List Entry</li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Helper Code:

```
Template.MyTemplate.helpers({
  checked() {
    let liClass = '';
    let imgClass = '';
    //your checked condition
    if(document.getElementById('myCheckBox').checked) {
      let liClass = 'checked';
      let imgClass = 'updatedstyle';
    }
    return {
      li: liClass,
      img: imgClass
    };
  }
});
```

That way you can bind multiple classes with different names to the checked input value.